# Docker: Jenkins container can't access internet on QNAP device

Tags: jenkins, docker, containers, qnap

I try to get the Docker image ([1.651.3](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/1.617/Dockerfile) or latest version) running on my QNAP NAS using the internal ContainerStation.

Just using the default settings without setting any parameters or binding any resource, I can't access the internet. I already tried the NAT or Host network mode, but this would make no difference.

**Stacktrace**:

```
Oct 02, 2016 1:55:07 PM javax.jmdns.impl.HostInfo newHostInfo                                                                   
WARNING: Could not intialize the host network interface on nullbecause of an error: 5929616b9f0b: 5929616b9f0b: unknown error   
java.net.UnknownHostException: 5929616b9f0b: 5929616b9f0b: unknown error                                                        
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)                                                             
    at javax.jmdns.impl.HostInfo.newHostInfo(HostInfo.java:75)                                                              
    at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.<init>(JmDNSImpl.java:407)                                                                
    at javax.jmdns.JmDNS.create(JmDNS.java:60)                                                                              
    at hudson.DNSMultiCast$1.call(DNSMultiCast.java:32)                                                                     
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)                         
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)                                                             
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)                                      
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)                                      
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)                                                                                
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 5929616b9f0b: unknown error                                                           
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)                                                           
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)                                                       
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)                                              
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)                                                             
    ... 9 more
```

**Using bash:**

```
$ ping google.de     
ping: unknown host
```

Any idea what might be the problem? Any other docker image can access the internet, only this image has these problems.

Comment: Hello can you please put your Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm using the default jenkins dockerfile: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/1.617/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently experienced the same problem and in my case it turned out to be caused by the ACL lists on the QNAP, preventing the *jenkins* user in the container from reading the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` files.

Here's how I fixed it. Perhaps it can be of some help to you as well:

1. ssh to the QNAP

   `$ ssh admin@<your IP or domain name here>`
2. Manually create a *jenkins* user on the QNAP with UID 1000 (the same
   UID as the *jenkins* user in the container)

   `$ useradd -u 1000 -M -s /bin/false jenkins`
3. Log into the QNAP web interface
4. Navigate to **Control panel** -> **Users**
5. Click the **Edit Shared Folder Permissions** icon for the **jenkins** user
6. Tick the **RW** checkbox (Read/Write access) for the *Container* folder
   and click **Apply**
7. Start your Jenkins container

*Disclaimer: I am no sysadmin so I don't know whether this approach would cause any security issues on your system. You may want to look into that before giving outside access to your Jenkins web interface... :)*